# Split the Tuple with strings with the format as shown Below

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, tuples

Can anyone please help me on how to split the tuple show below? I have x with the tuple printed below. I need only Street Name or Street number or only Country or all in few cases

```
>>> print(x)
(OrderedDict([('AddressNumber', '1893'), 
              ('StreetNamePreDirectional', 'W'), 
              ('StreetName', 'Malvern'), 
              ('StreetNamePostType', 'Ave'),
              ('Po#', '2425'), 
              ('PlaceName', 'Fullerton'), 
              ('StateName', 'CA'), 
              ('ZipCode', '92833')]), 
  'Street Address')
```

I am looking to get Address Number, StreetPredirectional, Street name, Place Name, StateName, Zip Code concatenated as below:

```
    ---Expected Output----
Print (AddressNumber+StreetNamePreDirectional+StreetName+StateName)
Output:1893 W Malvern Ave, Fullerton, CA
```

I dont want PO# in this case. I should be able to select desired tags such as Street name and number or Only place name or only country sometimes.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? You can index into the tuple then use keys to get the appropriate values from the ordered dictionary.

Comment: Can you be any more specific than "sometimes"?

Comment: what you want exactly? We are here to help you but you have to be more specific while asking any question.

Comment: Hello Guys, sorry on that. I have updated my question with "Expect Output". Some times, I need to grab the whole address (Address, street, zip, CA) and sometimes only Street name. So, I should be able to print or concatenate each of the tags (Street Name, Zip) individually...Hope I am clear Now..Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my answer. I sliced only the ordered dictionary out of the tuple first and then changed it to regular dictionary and finally concatenated all my dictionary values to make it look like a address.
** I also have the option to omit the zip code, or street name in my final formatted address by only selecting the dictionary values I need. Thanks to all who made time to look at this

```
z=list(x[0:1]) #convert the list
y=z[:1][0] #select only  OrderedDict

p=dict(y) #convert to regular dictionary

# pull individual items to make an formatted address
main_address=p['AddressNumber']+' '+ p['StreetNamePreDirectional']+' '+ p['StreetName'] +' '+  p['StreetNamePostType']+','+ p['PlaceName']+','+ p['StateName']+','+ p['ZipCode']

print(main_address)
>>>output: 1893 W Malvern Ave,Fullerton,CA,92833
```